# Why is this resistor only connected on one side?

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, pcb-assembly

I have taken a photo against the light so you can see through the board. It seems the circled resistor is only connected on one side. My hypothesis is that there is more than one version of this circuit board and another version has a capacitor or something in the empty space below the resistor. But for ease of manufacturing all boards have the resistor. Is this correct or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: It might be for a test fixture.

Comment: Which resistor?

Comment: You should mark the resistor, you refer to, because from this picture we can't be sure which one. We can only guess, because there may be concealed connections on other layers. My assumption is you refer to the 3.3 kΩ (exponent guessed) right next to the MELF-Diode. Am I right? If so add it to your question and I recommend validating your assumption by measurements.

Comment: Circled the resistor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a two layer board.

Comment: The pads next to it look like might be a pin header or jumper. It is possible it is unused, or used during manufacture to test something or perhaps shorting the pins makes the device go in service mode.

Comment: Please explain how it is only connected on one side? is the component that it ties to not loaded? (the through hole component?)

Comment: @VoltageSpike There is no component there, just two empty connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can provide more information on the board. Are there no connections or components on the other side of the board?
There is usually no 'use' for an unconnected resistor.

Otherwise this is likely done for manufacturing or testing reasons.
Perhaps the resistor is used for probing a certain setting or the board exists in multiple configurations where for instance an option is 'installed' or changed by connecting a jumper (0 ohm resistor) or another component between the close pads that are also visible.

To get the real reason you must ask the manufacturer :-)